# Maximum principle for several complex variables

Tags: several-complex-variables

Suppose that we have an analytic function on the polydisc {$ \{z \in \mathbb{C}^n: \left|z_i\right| < 1, \forall i=1,\dots,n \} $} and continuous on the boundary. Can a non-constant function take the maximum value outside of the distinguished boundary {$ \{z \in \mathbb{C}^n: \left|z_i\right| = 1, \forall i=1,\dots,n \} $}?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341307/maximum-modulus-principle-for-several-variables) shows that if the maximum modulus is achieved at an interior point, then the function is constant. Therefore the maximum must be achieved on the topological boundary. But I cannot prove (or disprove) that the maximum must be achieved on the distinguished boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***No, this can never happen***: seeing this when the complex domain is the polydisc requires the understanding of what [its topological boundary](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Polydisc) is, so we'll precisely do this, and prove the statement by *reductio ad absurdum*. 
Let's start by giving the following definitions:

- $\Bbb D_i =\{z_i\in\Bbb C\mid |z_i|< 1\}\triangleq \Bbb T_i$ is the open unit disc on the $i$-th complex plane of $\Bbb C^n$,  $i=1,\ldots, n$,
- $\overline{\Bbb D}_i =\{z_i\in\Bbb C\mid |z_i|\le 1\}$ is its closure and
- $\partial \Bbb D_i =\{z_i\in\Bbb C\mid |z_i|= 1\}$ is its boundary.

We have that

- $\Bbb D^n\simeq {\Bbb D}_1 \times \cdots \times {\Bbb D_i}\times \cdots \times {\Bbb D}_n=\times_{i=1}^n \Bbb D_i$ is the ordinary unit polidisc,
- $\Bbb T^n\simeq \partial{\Bbb D}_1 \times \cdots \times \partial{\Bbb D_i}\times \cdots \times \partial{\Bbb D}_n=\times_{i=1}^n \partial{\Bbb D}_i =\times_{i=1}^n\Bbb T_i$ is its [distinguished boundary](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Bergman-Shilov_boundary) i.e. the $n$-torus,
- $\Gamma_\nu= \overline{\Bbb D}_1 \times \cdots \times \partial \Bbb D_\nu\times \cdots \times \overline{\Bbb D}_n$ is its $\nu$-boundary sheet, $\nu=1,\ldots, n$.

Finally, we have that the topological boundary of the unit polydisc is the union of all $n$ of its boundary sheets
$$
\partial \Bbb D^n =\bigcup_{\nu=1}^n \Gamma_\nu
$$
As we can see, $\Bbb T^n\subsetneq \partial \Bbb D^n$.

Now assume that there exists a non constant function $f$, holomorphic on $\Bbb D^n$ and continuous on $\Bbb D^n\cup \partial \Bbb D^n$, that has a maximum on a boundary point $z_0=(z_{01},\ldots, z_{0n})\in \partial \Bbb D^n \setminus \Bbb T^n$. This means that at least one of its complex coordinates, say the $k$-th one, does not belong to $\partial {\Bbb D}_k$ but instead belongs to the interior of $\overline{\Bbb D}_k$ i.e. to ${\Bbb D}_k$. But then we are done, since now we can define a function $f_k$ as
$$
f_k(z_k)=f(z_{01}, \ldots,\underbrace{z_k}_k, \ldots, z_{0n})=f(z)|_{\substack{z_i=z_{0i} \\i\neq k}}
$$
which is a function of one complex variable on the disk ${\Bbb D}_k$ (that a holomorphic function of several complex variables is  holomorphic respect to each of its single variables is the elementary converse of Hartogs'lemma) which is continuous on $\overline{\Bbb D}_k$ and moreover reaches a maximum on an interior point of ${\Bbb D}_k$, which is impossible in view of the standard maximum principle of functions of a complex variable. Thus
$$
\max_{z\in \Bbb D^n\cup \partial \Bbb D^n} f(z) = f(z_0)\implies z_0\in \Bbb T^n.
$$